# How do I keep the same font height in a terminal when some characters are with a overbar?

Tags: python, terminal, fonts

I am trying to display to terminal strings for which some characters are to be represented with an overbar. For example (in Python):

```
print('1',u'1\u0305')
```

However, non-overbar characters seem to be taken from a different fonts family.

[image]

Is there any way to display the `non-overbar` characters with the same font family of the `overbar` characters?

Comment: What terminal are you using? As far as I know this is 100% controlled by your terminal, and nothing to do with python.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is not language-specific, but terminal-specific. I included the python snippet just to illustrate the issue with repeatable steps. I am using bash and zsh (but I would not mind having a solution for windows terminals as well)